# PHP AWS HTTP error: Unable to open using mode r+ fopen

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have been transferring my PHP server files from windows to ubuntu 14.04 and my script broke... 
I'm getting the error when downloading from S3.

```
        $result = $s3->getObject(array(
            'Bucket' => AWS_S3_BUCKET,
            'Key'    => $imgName,
            'SaveAs' => $targetPath
        )); //the exception is thrown!
```

**The exception message:**

> Error executing GetObject on http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/file AWS
>   HTTP error: Unable to open ../../downloads/file using mode r+:
>   fopen(../../downloads/file).

`sudo chmod -R 777 wwwfolder didn't work`

Any ideas?

### ** Update **

Found a Hax/Workaround.... adding touch($targetPath) before $s3->getObject method fixes the problem... but **why**? I tried on different ubuntu server (same version) and there it works (without touch; and i don't know how it was configured..).
What about now? Any ideas?

Comment: do you have your folder structure in place? ubuntu's file system is case sensitive make sure that the case matches

Comment: hey thanks for the answer... using touch($targetPath) and fopen($targetPath)  gives no error (generating and reading file localy)... so i dont think this is the problem here :/

Comment: have you tried the full path instead of `../../` ?

Comment: Tried right now... still the same :/

Comment: [Take a look at this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www/46371#46371) Solution 1 worked for me!